# TelemetryClient is not logging Session_Id and User_Id for CustomEvents

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-application-insights

I am using MS BotFramework for NodeJS SDK where trying to log all applicationInsights data through ApplicationInsightsTelemetryClient and TelemetryLoggerMiddleware APIs.

My project is based on NodeJS Javascript version and the reference NodeJS project is in Typescript (https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/tree/master/templates/Virtual-Assistant-Template/typescript/samples/sample-assistant)

The Typescript project works fine. But my JavaScript project is not storing the Session_ID and User_ID for my customEvent.

Though I got the root cause as well. It's inside NPM Package not in my code. ;(

TelemetryClient.js’ runTelemetryProcessors method is not attaching the activity object to the contextObect.correlationContext property.

```
TelemetryClient.prototype.runTelemetryProcessors = function (envelope, contextObjects) {
       var accepted = true;
       var telemetryProcessorsCount = this._telemetryProcessors.length;
       if (telemetryProcessorsCount === 0) {
           return accepted;
       }
       contextObjects = contextObjects || {};
       contextObjects['correlationContext'] = CorrelationContextManager_1.CorrelationContextManager.getCurrentContext();
       for (var i = 0; i < telemetryProcessorsCount; ++i) {
           try {
               var processor = this._telemetryProcessors[i];
               if (processor) {
                   if (processor.apply(null, [envelope, contextObjects]) === false) {
                       accepted = false;
                       break;
                   }
               }
           }
           catch (error) {
               accepted = true;
               Logging.warn("One of telemetry processors failed, telemetry item will be sent.", error, envelope);
           }
       }
       return accepted;
   };
```

If I make it working with activity object attachment to the contextOjbect than below processor method of ApplicationInsightsTelemetryClient will attach the userId and sessionId for all custom events.

```
exports.ApplicationInsightsTelemetryClient = ApplicationInsightsTelemetryClient;
/* Define the telemetry initializer function which is responsible for setting the userId. sessionId and some other values
* so that application insights can correlate related events.
*/
function addBotIdentifiers(envelope, context) {
    if (context.correlationContext && context.correlationContext.activity) {
        const activity = context.correlationContext.activity;
        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-string-literal
        const telemetryItem = envelope.data['baseData']; // TODO: update when envelope ts definition includes baseData
        const userId = activity.from ? activity.from.id : '';
        const channelId = activity.channelId || '';
        const conversationId = activity.conversation ? activity.conversation.id : '';
        // set user id and session id
        envelope.tags[appInsights.defaultClient.context.keys.userId] = channelId + userId;
        envelope.tags[appInsights.defaultClient.context.keys.sessionId] = conversationId;
        // Add additional properties
        telemetryItem.properties = telemetryItem.properties || {};
        telemetryItem.properties.activityId = activity.id;
        telemetryItem.properties.channelId = channelId;
        telemetryItem.properties.activityType = activity.type;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Any thought, what I am missing here?

Comment: It sounds like you have it working. What is the current issue? Which code is YOUR code, which is from VIRTUAL ASSISTANT, and which is from WHAT NPM PACKAGE? How are you using `TelemetryLoggerMiddleware`?

Comment: Are you still experiencing an issue with this?